# Give an example when $\chi(1)$ is strictly less than $[\chi, \chi]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I was recently learning representation theory and I have a question. $\chi$ is the character of an finite abelian group, say $G$. I am wondering what is an example for $\chi(1)$ is strictly less than $[\chi,\chi]$, where $\chi(1) = dim(V)$, dimension of the representation or vector space and $[\chi,\chi] = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g}\chi(g)\overline{\chi(g)}$.

Since for finite abelian group, all its representation is of dimension 1 and there are $|G|$ such inequivalent representations. Somehow I can only prove that they are equal. I was wondering if anyone could give a hint on how to show that $\chi(1) < [\chi,\chi]$ at some cases. Thanks.

Comment: They are equal iff all constituents of the character are distinct.

Comment: Hi Tobias, thanks. I am wondering if this is always the case if G is a finite abelian group. I saw a corollary that says every irreducible representation of finite abelian group is of dimension 1 and there are |G| such inequivalent irreducible representations.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "this". What I said holds for any finite abelian group.

Comment: Alright, thanks.